# Facing problem on SSH by using NETMIKO library to access Huawei system

Tags: python, alarm, netmiko

I am facing problem with my code on python using NETMIKO library for access at Huawei system.

I am logging NE and it logged in but When I want to find any large data it shows problem but if I just want to find small information like NE ID or active alarm, it shows that.

import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger("netmiko")

host1 = {

```
"host": "Ip Address",

"username": "user_name", 

"password": "password",

"device_type": "huawei",

"global_delay_factor": 0.1,
```

}
net_connect=Netmiko(**host1)

command1 = ["display alarm active alarm-name MUT_LOS"]

print("Connected to:", net_connect.find_prompt())

output = net_connect.send_config_set(command1, delay_factor=.5)

net_connect.disconnect()

print(output)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not able to get the large amount of data using Netmiko library. When I used to get alarm of specific things like MUT_LOS or other, if the data was large then it will show error comment.